# How to fit Content into Div Container

Tags: html, css

`InnerText div` doesnt fit to the `outer div Text` if i give a top offset to the `InnerText div` it fits perfectly but i cant hardcord this as entire html is created in Runtime using C# application, i cant find the reason why is this happening.
Please bear with me as i am totally noob in html and Css.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9'/>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>body {background-color:#d4c3d4 ; overflow: hidden; }</style>     
</head>
<body>  
    <div id='text' style='height:110px;'>
        <div id='innerText' style='position:relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap'>
            <span class='article' style='padding-left:4px;'>
                <span style="font-size:110px">
                    <span style="color:#FF8C00">
                        <span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">[Title] - [date] - [description]</span>                       
                    </span>
                </span> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

> Output:
>   [image: Html Output]

**Edited:**

I Cant change the height of div as it plays in LED every Pixel matters and increasing its height change an entire resoltion

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `height: 110px` for *outer div* and the `font-size:110px` in the `span` this makes one *parent div* smaller than the text it contains,

**the solution** :

1- change the `height` to bigger value or delete it from style. *or*

2- change the `font-size` to smaller value

as for automatic creation for html , I recommend shrinking the size of the `innertext` to: say 80px.

Comment: so how can i calculate the ratio between these two.

Comment: choose a suitable one , like 80/110 = 0.72 , that would fit .i guess

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Only Remove `style=height:110px;` I added a border for you see Result :

```css
body {background-color:#d4c3d4 ; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<div id='text' style='border: 1px solid red;'>
   <div id='innerText' style='position:relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap'>
        <span class='article' style='padding-left:4px;'>
            <span style="font-size:110px">
                <span style="color:#FF8C00">
                    <span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">[Title] - [date] - [description]</span>                       
                    </span>
                </span> 
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2 :** use `min-height` instead of `height` :

```css
body {background-color:#d4c3d4 ; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<div id='text' style='min-height:110px;border: 1px solid red;'>
   <div id='innerText' style='position:relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap'>
        <span class='article' style='padding-left:4px;'>
            <span style="font-size:110px">
                <span style="color:#FF8C00">
                    <span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">[Title] - [date] - [description]</span>                       
                    </span>
                </span> 
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {background-color:#d4c3d4 ; overflow: hidden; }
#text {
border:thin black solid;
width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='text' >
        <div id='innerText' style='position:relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;'>
            <span class='article' style='padding-left:4px;'>
                <span style="font-size:110px">
                    <span style="color:#FF8C00">
                        <span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">[Title] - [date] - [description]</span>                       
                    </span>
                </span> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is this the same that you want?
I have removed **white-space : nowrap;**

You can use **white-space : break-word** so that the extra contents will be in new line if it doesn't fit on the same line.